# Yarn script fails, but works when running directly in terminal

Tags: javascript, linux, git, yarnpkg

I'm using this script to get all the todos in my codebase sorted by date:

```
git grep -il todo: \\*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx,css,scss,html} | xargs -n1 git blame -c -e | sed -E 's/^.+\\.com>\\s+//' | LC_ALL=C grep -F 'todo: ' | sort
```

It works when I run it directly in the terminal. If I run it as a Yarn script, I get:

```
usage: git blame [<options>] [<rev-opts>] [<rev>] [--] <file>

    <rev-opts> are documented in git-rev-list(1)
```

I also get the error when I run it using npm. How can I fix this?

Comment: Your command is bash specific, so you need to make sure it runs with bash and not with sh. The easiest way to do this is to put it in a script with a bash shebang, then run the script from npm

Comment: Well, bash, and zsh, and ksh, and ksh93. Also tcsh and csh. And fish.